# Crash with MapKit on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, mapkit

I have not been able to reproduce this particular crash myself but it has been reported via our crash reporting tool and is being experienced by several hundred of our users. Finding it hard to debug or reproduce.

It happens on all hardware platforms but only on iOS 6. Any help or insights will be highly appreciated.

Exception Type:SIGSEGVCode:SEGV_ACCERR

```
Fatal Exception
Thread 0 Crashed
0    MapKit      _remove(objc_object*, MKQuadTrieNode*) + 13
1    MapKit  -[MKQuadTrie remove:] + 54
2    MapKit  -[MKAnnotationContainerView observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 252
3    Foundation  NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 272
4    Foundation  NSKeyValueWillChange + 572
5    Foundation  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 180
6    Foundation  NSKVOForwardInvocation + 130
7    CoreFoundation  ___forwarding___ + 626
8    CoreFoundation  _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
9    MapKit  -[MKUserLocation _updateCoordinate] + 106
10   MapKit  -[MKUserLocation setLocation:] + 106
11   MapKit  -[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) locationManagerUpdatedLocation:] + 994
12   CoreFoundation  -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 206
13   MapKit  -[MKLocationManager _reportLocationStatus:] + 66
14   MapKit  -[MKLocationManager locationProvider:didUpdateLocation:] + 1540
15   MapKit  -[MKCoreLocationProvider locationManager:didUpdateLocations:] + 864
16   CoreLocation    -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:] + 1614
17   CoreLocation    __CLClientInvokeCallback_block_invoke_0 + 64
18   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
19   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 160
20   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1450
21   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
22   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
23   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
24   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
25   App Name   main.m line 14 main + 14
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. You can reproduce the crash by sending the application to the background, leaving it there for a while, and then bringing it to the foreground. I think the problem has to do with memory warnings and views while on the background.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the delegate method of the locationManager to nil in the dealloc method of the class you are using it in

Something like this:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
}
```

What might be happening is that the object is being deallocated (maybe due to low memory) and the location manager is trying to send a message to a non existing delegate.